# Quaternionic representation of a real matrix with size $4\times 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, quaternions

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{4}\in M_4(\mathbb R)$.
Apply inverse of the isomorphis $\chi:\mathbb H\to M_4(\mathbb R)$ where $\chi(a)=A$ and 
$$\chi (a_{0}+a_{1}i+a_{2}j+a_{3}k)=\begin{bmatrix}‎
‎a_{0} &‎ -‎a_{1} & a_{3} &‎ -‎a_{2} \\‎
‎a_{1} & a_{0} &‎ -‎a_{2} &‎ -‎a_{3} \\‎
-‎a_{3} & a_{2} & a_{0} &‎ -‎a_{1} \\‎
‎a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{1} & a_{0}‎
‎\end{bmatrix}.$$
Since every real matrix with size $4\times 4$ is represented by a quaternion, I want to find $a$ as $a=a_0+a_1 i+a_2 j+a_3 k$.

I don't know how i use inverse of $\chi$.

Comment: How do you define $\chi$ in the first place?  You're not giving us any context at all here.

Comment: O.k. I edit now

Comment: Your edit does not answer my question.  I'm looking for something like
$$
\chi(a_0 + a_1 i + a_2j + a_3k) = \cdots ?
$$

Comment: Note that there is no isomorphism (in any usual category, other than groups) from $\mathbb{H}$ onto $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ since $\mathbb{H}$ is a real vector space of dimension $4$ while $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space of dimension $16$.

Comment: I edited this..... Yes the $\chi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @444:  As I said, it's not an isomorphism *onto* $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ for the reasons stated.  For example, the diagonal matrix with entries $1,1,1,0$ is not in the image of $\chi$.  So $\chi^{-1}$ is not defined on all of $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ in any kind of natural way.

Comment: $\Bbb H$ and $M_4(\Bbb R)$ are **not** isomorphic. There are left and right regular representations $\Bbb H\to M_4(\Bbb R)$, and there is an $\Bbb R$-algebra isomorphism $\Bbb H\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb H\to M_4(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\chi$ is not an isomorphism from $ \mathbb H$ and $M_4(\mathbb R)$, but from $ \mathbb H$ and the subspace $V$ of $M_4(\mathbb R)$ spanned by the matrices:
$$
E=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} \qquad
I=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
J=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix} \qquad
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
With the correspondence
$$
1 \to E\quad i \to I \quad j \to J \quad k \to K
$$
Note that $V$ is a space of dimension  $4$ over $\mathbb R$ and $\chi$ is invertible from $V$ to $\mathbb H$ in a an obvious way.